Understanding によっても
I wonder what is the nuance of も in this sentence:

君がこの事実を知った事によっても我々の未来は刻一刻とその巡路を変化させているのだ

How the meaning will change if there's no も? Does 君がこの事実を知った事によっても mean "by you knowing the truth, (contrary to our expectations)..."?

(Source: Boruto Two Blue Vortex ch. 13)

This も means "also", "even" or "as well". Big events affect the future, which is taken for granted, but small events like "your recognition of this fact" is also something that affects the future. This idea is known as butterfly effect.

今君がこの事実を知った事によっても、我々の未来は刻一刻とその巡路を変化させているのだ。
Also/Even by you knowing this fact right now, our future is changing its course moment by moment.


I'm no expert in the Japanese language, but I think that も here means "even". も have many different meanings, and what it means depends on context. The sentence thus is:

君がこの事実を知った事によっても我々の未来は刻一刻とその巡路を変化させているのだ
Even that you now know this fact, the future is still changing every moment.

I'm not so sure if my translation is entirely correct, but I'm pretty sure も means "even though" here.

No, I don't think this も is "even though", because によって is functionally a particle, and particle + も only becomes "even though" when the predicate is negative (that includes 少ない or ～がたい).

@broccoliforest OK, thanks for pointing out! So it is "even" alone, then. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Uh, any comment from downvoter?
